# How to cite text of bibitem?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'm struggling to enter the whole text of citation. I have added bibliography into the document:

```
\begin{document}
...
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{stern} 
Frederick Stern, Conditional expectation of the duration in the classical ruin problem, Math. Mag. 48 (4) (1975) 200-203
.....
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to cite the text without mentioning the number?

For example, I want to insert all information of bibitem{stern} in document:

*We present a unified approach which uses generating functions to prove and extend some results that were obtained in [Frederick Stern, Conditional expectation of the duration in the classical ruin problem, Math. Mag. 48 (4) (1975) 200-203]*

`\cite{stern}` gives just a number - [1]

Comment: Have a look to https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/bibliography_management_with_bibtex and then be more explicit with your question, show an example of what do you have and what would you like to have

Comment: Since you are using a manually generated `thebibliography` environment and not `biblatex` I have retagged your question.

Comment: But to address the question: If you are writing your bibliography entries manually in `thebibliography` then it is not easy to repeat the entire citation in the document body. You'd have to somehow grab the entire entry data and store it for later processing. That's not totally out of the question, but really quite tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define new macros to do this. One way is to take a leaf out of harvard.sty and write

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%% this is from harvard.sty -- used inside "long" cites to prevent expansion
{\catcode`\:=12 \catcode`\-=12 \catcode`\>=12 \catcode`\<=12 %
 \gdef\codeof#1{\expandafter\codeof@\meaning#1<-:}%
 \gdef\codeof@#1:->#2<-:{#2}}
%% wrapper around the bibitems
\def\bibwrap#1#2{%
\bibitem{#1}#2%
\if@filesw{\def\next{{#2}}%
           \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\long@bibcite{#1}\codeof\next}}%
\fi}
%% commands for "long" cites
\def\long@bibcite{\@newl@bel y} %in .aux file
\def\long@cite#1{\csname y@#1\endcsname% for use by user
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\citation{#1}}}
\def\longcite#1{[\long@cite{#1}]}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
... \longcite{stern}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibwrap{stern}{Frederick Stern, Conditional expectation of the duration in the classical ruin problem, Math. Mag. 48 (4) (1975) 200-203}
.....
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

(I don't quite remember where I first found the code snippets in question, they are not entirely original.)

Comment: Thank you very much!